# How to display the correct database name?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to run this code under every database

```
 exec sp_MSForEachDB @command1 = 'SELECT DB_NAME() AS [CurrentDatabase], CompanyName, CASE WHEN IsCommited = 1 THEN ''Yes'' WHEN IsCommited = 0 THEN ''No'' END as CaseIsInCommit FROM  ?.dbo.CompanyCase;'
```

The data for the example will be [(db1, Company1, 1), (db2, Company2, 1), (db3, Company3, 1)] This code is suppose to get the database name, the company name from the table, and state whether it has been committed or not but the problem I'm having is that it will display the results like

The data for the example will be [(db1, Company1, 1), (db2, Company2, 1), (db3, Company3, 1)]

```
 CurrentDatabase     CampanyName     IsCommited
       db1             Company1         Yes
       db1             Company2         Yes
       db1             Company3         Yes
```

What is happening is it keeps saying db1 instead of saying db2 or db3 for the other companies. How can I get it to it to say db2 and db3 for the correct company? It should look like this

```
 CurrentDatabase     CampanyName     IsCommited
       db1             Company1         Yes
       db2             Company2         Yes
       db3             Company3         Yes
```

I thought `DB_NAME()` would do the job but it seems to be stuck on the same database while the other columns move to the next one.

Comment: try replacing it with `?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to change to the database.  Try this:

```
exec sp_MSForEachDB @command1 = 'USE [?]; SELECT DB_NAME() AS [CurrentDatabase], CompanyName, CASE WHEN IsCommited = 1 THEN ''Yes'' WHEN IsCommited = 0 THEN ''No'' END as CaseIsInCommit FROM  ?.dbo.CompanyCase;'
```

And [here](https://rextester.com/FEEUR76725) is a simple example.

Comment: Thank you. It worked great! I'll give you the best answer when it will let me in a couple minutes. What does the `?` mean if you happen to know?

Comment: @DaBeau96 . . . That is just a placeholder for the database name.  This is a common way of parameterizing a string -- although the database name is not really a parameter and SQL Server does not (generally) use `?`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not changing which database to execute on.Here is a way to do it with some dynamic SQL,

```
    DECLARE @DBNames TABLE
    (
        ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)
        ,DBNAME nVARCHAR(200)

    )

INSERT INTO @DBNames
select distinct
 db_name(s_mf.database_id) dbName 
    from
        sys.master_files s_mf
    where
        s_mf.state = 0 and -- ONLINE
        has_dbaccess(db_name(s_mf.database_id)) = 1 -- Only look at databases to which we have access
    and db_name(s_mf.database_id) not in ('master','tempdb','model','msdb','distribution')
    and db_name(s_mf.database_id) not like 'MSDB%'
    and db_name(s_mf.database_id) not like 'Report%'
    and type=1
    order by 
        db_name(s_mf.database_id)

        DECLARE @Count INT, @Counter INT,   @CurrentName NVARCHAR(260)
    SELECT @Count = COUNT(*) FROM @DBNames m
    SET @Counter = 1

DECLARE @SQL1 as nVARCHAR (MAX)

    WHILE @Counter <= @Count
    BEGIN
        SELECT @CurrentName = DBNAME FROM @Modules m WHERE ID = @Counter
         set @SQL1 ='USE ' + @CurrentName  +';' +  'SELECT '+@CurrentName+' [CurrentDatabase], CompanyName, CASE WHEN IsCommited = 1 THEN ''Yes'' WHEN IsCommited = 0 THEN ''No'' END as CaseIsInCommit FROM  ?.dbo.CompanyCase;'
         exec @SQL1

        SET @Counter = @Counter + 1
    END
```